# Why don't EXECUTE permissions get published by database project in VS2017 CE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using VS2017 Community Edition to develop a database project published to SQL Server 2008R2, the EXECUTE permissions on stored procedures do not make it into either the debug or the published database (both on the same server cluster).  EXECUTE are the only explicit permissions I need (others are via roles, and already in the server), so this might apply to other permissions too.  I am granting the permission explicitly at the end of the proc source, and if I run the source script directly on the server the grant works as expected.

The box to ignore permissions is not checked in either the 'Drop' tab or the Exclude list of the 'Ignore' tab of the Advanced Deployment Settings dialog; nor is the 'Drop permissions not in source' (although that does not seem relevant).

I'll tag this with both SQL Server 2008 and VS in case it's a versions issue, but I suspect that I just haven't told VS what to do properly.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Publish profile XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseName>WCCProjectConnectDBDev</TargetDatabaseName>
    <DeployScriptFileName>WCCProjectConnectDB.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: can you include your publish profile xml in the question?

Comment: Sure, where would I find it?

Comment: Added above; couldn't work out how to delete my earlier comment.

Comment: Did you include a `GO` between the procedure body and the `GRANT EXECUTE`? If not, the statement becomes part of the procedure itself. Also, you can verify that omitting permissions is the problem by having the publish generate a script instead of deploying directly, and checking whether the `GRANT` is in the script or not.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - no I didn't!  Thank you. I'll remove the VS tag as it's actually a basic SQL Server question.  Thanks again.